# Getting the value of a var or let in Swift during Step Over (Xcode 6.0.1 / 6.0)

Tags: xcode

I don’t know if it’s a bug in Xcode or if Apple have changed how to get a value of a variable or constant in Swift, but during Step Over when I hover over a name of a variable/constant there’s no popover with it’s value

Thanks for any help

Comment: Do you solve the problem? I have the same now..((